# How to convert 2 bytes from byte[] to a Char / short (2 bytes)?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

My goal is to convert 2 bytes to a Char.

The input will be from a `byte[]` then converted to char. My initial strategy was to use bitwise operations.

My expected result: `0xFF << 8 | 0xFF` equals to 0xFFFF. It does. But, in practice it does not because before the bitwise operations, I need to store the data in `byte[]`.

My actual result: Due to the way I access the data. `(byte) 0xFF << 8 | (byte) 0xFF` will equal to -1.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF};

int integer = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]; // -1 or 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: What would you be doing with this char - is it actually a letter or digit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
int integer = (bytes[0] & 0xff) << 8 | (bytes[1] & 0xff);
```

Which gives the expected value of 65535.

Comment: `0xFF` remove the sign notation, right? Is this the "two complement" system?

Comment: Yes, all integer types in Java use two's complement, so a `byte` with all bits set, i.e. 0xff, is interpreted as -1. Using `b & 0xff` widens `b` to an `int` using the low 8 bits of the `byte`, so it's interpreted as unsigned.