# Can Java's byte actually store 32bit?

Tags: java

My goal is to understand how byte is stored in Java.

```
System.out.println("(byte) 0xFF:\r\n" +
                   Integer.toBinaryString((byte) 0xFF));
```

My expected result of `(byte) 0xFF` is `0xFF`.

My actual result of `(byte) 0xFF` is `0xFFFFFFFF`

The output:

```
(byte) 0xFF:
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

If this is true, does storing negative number in `byte` actually is no different than storing negative number in `int`?

Comment: You could print `-1 * INTEGER.MAX_VALUE`, to compare

Comment: Bytes use 8 bits, not 32 bits. The (only) method `Integer.toBinaryString()` has an `int` argument, not `byte`. You are simply calling the method like `Integer.toBinaryString(-1)`.

Comment: The answer to this question should become obvious if you look up `Integer.toBinaryString` in the documentation, and notice what parameter type it accepts. If that doesn't answer the question, try putting `twos complement java` into a search engine. Also refer to your own [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732418/how-to-convert-2-bytes-from-byte-to-a-char-short-2-bytes) for context; essentially the same thing is happening here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i don't this is the case, `Integer.toBinaryString(0x00)` would output `0`.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't at all contradict what I'm saying. Java may trim leading `0`s from the result, but that has nothing to do with the number of bytes being used to store the value. `0` is all zero bits no matter how many bits you use.

Comment: I agree with @user, sorry I can't tag, my laptop just broke. If I do bitwise AND, the top and bottom bits should have exact length of bits. That make sense. Let me iterate 0xFF in Java is 24 zeros, 8 ones, right?

Comment: Yes, 0xff is 000...011111111 and when you cast it to byte you are left with just the 11111111. Which is -1 in twos complement.

Comment: An integer overflow is when you provide a value too large to be represented and the sign is "switched" In this case you're trying to represent 255 as a byte which only goes to 127. Hence the sign switches. I don't understand why there is such a pushback against using the term overflow. It is also in the jls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) accepts an `int`. Your input was just autopromoted to `int`, hence it was represented with 32 digits (0xFF == -1 in two's complement, which promoted to int becomes 0xFFFFFFFF which is still -1 but represented with 32 bits, still in two's complement).

Notice that

> If the unsigned magnitude is zero, it is represented by a single zero character '0' ('\u0030'); otherwise, the first character of the representation of the unsigned magnitude will not be the zero character.

Which means that if there are leading 0s they won't be part of the output (unless the output is 0), which means you'll get less than 32 digits.

Comment: I see so if I do `0x02` which equals to `00000010` in binary. It will print out `10`. But in this case because everything is promoted to `int`, it will convert it to `0x00000002` and print it `10`. But.. in this case `(byte) 0xFF` is equals to `0x100` in two's complement. WAIT.... i think's it's not right.

Comment: @kidfrom *"But.. in this case (byte) 0xFF is equals to 0x100"* no, two's complement only makes sense when talking about the binary representation of a number, not the hexadecimal one.

Comment: You've missed a bit of a step. `int a = 0xff;` a would be 255 *and* it is still twos complement.  `byte b = (byte)0xff;` is -1 because it only has 8 bits and is twos complement.

Answer (score 0):

When the byte is implicitly re-cast as an integer, it sees the first bit as a sign bit and when it stretches out to be 4 bytes long, it retains it's value as negative. You've effectively overflowed to the smallest negative integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Java bytes are signed and can represent the values -128 to 127, and a hex value of 0xff is treated as -1. When you call Integer.toBinaryString, the byte is cast to an int, preserving the sign. The way this works is called sign extension, and the highest bit from the byte is copied all the way up. This is why you see 0xfffff...

To perform an unsigned conversion, mask the value with 0xff, which itself an int unless specified otherwise.

```
byte b = (byte) 0xff;
Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff);
```

And to answer your original question, Java doesn't really support a byte type as you might expect. It's always a 32-bit value except when dealing with byte arrays and byte buffers. Using a type of `byte` simply informs the JVM to perform certain type casting rules which have the effect of clearing or setting the upper bits accordingly.

Comment: I cant test this, my laptop just died. If a byte is 32-bit in JVM, then a short is 64-bit? What do you mean by `It's always a 32-bit`

Comment: I think this is not true. [Reference] (https://medium.com/android-news/java-when-to-use-n-8-0xff-and-when-to-use-byte-n-8-2efd82ae7dd7). Byte should be 8-bit not 32-bit.

Comment: I'm referring to an implementation detail. As far as the Java language is concerned, a byte is really a byte, and there's no way to expose that the underlying implementation is different. The JVM doesn't have a true byte type. The smallest it has is an int, and so byte and short are always internally 32-bit (at least). Except for arrays.